# Android API 12+ Download file access

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-12

I have an android app that downloads a zip file into the public downloads folder and then tries to unzip it. With the new file permissions in android 12, the only way I have been able to get this to work is by using the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. However, the play store keeps rejecting my app. How can I perform this operation with out needing the permission? The zip file is in the same directory it is being unzipped into.

```
File unzip_directory = new File(ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this,
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)[0], "zipfile");
if (!unzip_directory.exists()) unzip_directory.mkdirs();
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterById(download_id);
Cursor cursor = download_manager.query(query);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int fileUriIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI);
String fileUri = cursor.getString(fileUriIdx);
zip_file = new File(Uri.parse(fileUri).getPath());
ZipInputStream zip_stream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zip_file)); // crashes here open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: You only need the old WRITE permission to create a file in the public Download folder. So i do not understand which problem you would have. Please elaborate.

Comment: And for getExternalFilesDir() you do not need any permission. And getExternalFilesDir() does not bring you to the public Download folder.

Comment: `zip_file = new File(Uri.parse(fileUri).getPath())` Think that that will not work. Please have a look at value of getPath(). Then tell us.. Also tell value of fileUri.

Comment: @blackapps `zip_file = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/myzip.zip"` with exception `/storage/emulated/0/Download/myzip.zip: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: You have not told the value of String fileUri = cursor.getString(fileUriIdx); I think it starts with content://... and not with /storage/...

Comment: @blackapps That string above is the value from the cursor file url. It is the same destination I sent when I create setup the Download Manager 
`File destination = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "zipfile.zip");
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destination));`

Comment: Well then look also at the value of destination.getAbsolutePath() and ser that it is different.